# Syntax issues with vim when open a file from another editor

Tags: vim, syntax, editor

I used to edit all my files with Vim and i never got problems with it. 
But, yesterday i take back some work from a developper and open the files he gaves me.

I don't really know why but Vim reads it as one line only :

```
<?php ^M $lesdatas=file_get_contents('datas.dat'); ^M $datas=explode('=>',$lesdatas);
foreach ($datas as $data) { ^M // comment ^M $vals=explode('==',$data);
```

Etc etc...

Looks like vim can't interpret ^ M as a 'Enter'.

How can i convert the file to read it normally ?

Thx for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the file is encoded in (traditional) Apple Mac format, using Carriage Return (CR, `^M`) as the end-of-line delimiter (Windows uses CR-LF `^M^J`, Unix LF `^J`). Try opening the file with

```
:edit ++ff=mac filename
```

If you need to open such files often, adapt your `'fileformats'` setting, as described under `:help fileformats`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert files definitly ?